# How to replicate CouchDB to a desktop browser?

Tags: couchdb, replication

I've heard that CouchDB can replicate to desktop browsers, such as: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na2yApM9ydw

How can a CouchDB database be replicated to a desktop browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web browser would have to be running a CouchDB instance or a "clone" that uses a compatible API, but uses a browser-based database under the hood. (like localStorage, IndexedDB, etc.)

There are several projects out there, namely: [BrowserCouch](http://mikeal.github.com/browsercouch/) and [IDBCouch](https://github.com/mikeal/IDBCouch)

BrowserCouch is a JavaScript-based implementation of Map/Reduce with the CouchDB API. IDBCouch leverages IndexedDB (a Mozilla project) for the same basic purpose.

Comment: How would you do this part? "The web browser would have to be running a CouchDB instance or a clone"

Comment: Well, that hasn't happened yet, but with other browser databases like IndexedDB, localStorage, WebSQL, etc. it could eventually show up.

Comment: "PouchDB is a Portable CouchDB, it is a near complete implementation of Apache CouchDB that runs natively in the browser using IndexedDB as its storage mechanism, it has the same data model as CouchDB, the same conflict resolution and most importantly, it replicates with CouchDB."

http://arandomurl.com/2012/03/27/pouchdb-is-couchdb-in-the-browser.html